# View Tagged Keywords in Blog Post

Tags: 2013, blog, tags, enterprise-keywords

I am trying to configure a Blog site for end users and I have already added the Enterprise keyword column to the list. However, I have noticed that I am unable to view any of the tags I inserted while writing the post. I would like the tags to show up just like they do on this site. Below the post and clickable. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to key tags like support is to enable on the **Posts list** via `List Settings > Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings` and make sure it is checked to **"Add an Enterprise Keywords column to this list and enable Keyword synchronization"**.

Once you enable it you will be get the tags.[Add tags to a blog post in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78765/add-tags-to-a-blog-post-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Hello,
That's already enabled. The issue isn't that the field isn't showing up when creating a blog post, it's that the tags aren't showing in the completed blog post when viewed after it's been created. They aren't showing up anywhere in the post.

Comment: did you check the view of the blog posts if that cloumn included in the view?

Comment: Yes, the column is included in the list view of the blog but when I go back to the blog's homepage, where the post layouts come into play (basic, boxed, inline) I am unable to see any keywords/tags.